# MsBuild pass PropertyGroup between projects

Tags: msbuild

I have two Visual Studio database projects.

```
Project A
Project B
 - References: Project A
```

Project A is an indipendent database project while Project B has a reference to A.
When I build Project B I have the following expected output from MsBuild:

```
------ Build started: Project: Project A, Configuration: Debug Any CPU 
--------- Build started: Project: Project B, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In **Project B** I have a property defined in the following way:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <MyProperty>MyValue</MyProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now, in both projects I have created a simple task that is executed before I Build the project and that print the value of the variable:
Project A, B:

```
  <Target Name="Print" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="MyProperty is: $(MyProperty)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

Unfortunately I get this behavior on MsBuild:

```
------ Build started: Project: Project A, Configuration: Debug Any CPU 
MyProperty is:
--------- Build started: Project: Project B, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
MyProperty is: MyValue
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have a reference to Project A in Project B with this configuration:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference IncludeProjectA.dbproj">
      <Name>ProjectA</Name>
      <Project>{f6546bef-cea7-4e7f-b6f1-cce1c06c7b1a}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there any way I can inject the value of MyProperty from Project B into Project A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about creating a "Targets" file to be shared across both projects? So you'll have something like `"DatabaseProjects.Targets"`, which will have the basic MSBuild header tag, and then your property group.

Then in Project A and Project B, **after** the configuration definitions, import the targets file with the import element, like `<Import Project="DatabaseProjects.Targets" />`

That way, the property won't be in any single project, but in a shared "targets import".

For added visibility, you could add the targets file to your projects as a linked 'none' / 'don't copy' file.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I did. I have created a custom Target that builds multiple projects and in each one pass the variables I need using the <MsBuild> tag.

Comment: Can you share your project file that was reused across projects?

Comment: There's really nothing special about it, you just need a standard MSBuild project file root element - `<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`. And then whatever properties you want within it, such as a `PropertyGroup`.